# Any new updates on @angular/google-maps for new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I cannot import any component for new updates on Markers based on the new update google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement. Cannot use   component in my angular app. It says it is not a known element of angular components.

```
`<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
    <div id="map">
      <google-map
        height="100%"
        width="100%"
        #map
        dndDropzone
        [center]="center"
        (mapMousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
        (dndDrop)="onDrop($event)"
        (mapClick)="onMapClick($event)"
      >
        @for (marker of markers; track $index) {
        <map-marker
          [position]="marker.position"
          [icon]="marker.icon!"
          (shapeChanged)="marker.markerShape"
          [draggable]="true"
        ></map-marker>

        }
      </google-map>
    </div>
  </ion-content>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It will be available at `@angular/google-maps` version 17.3

There was already a [commit](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/28525) 3 weeks ago to implement Advanced Marker for `@angular/google-maps` which was set to be released on version `17.3`. It is currently available on the [pre-released version of 17.3](https://github.com/angular/components/releases/tag/17.3.0-next.0).

To try it out, you can update your `@angular/google-maps` to beta version by running the following command in the terminal:

```
ng update @angular/google-maps --next
```

the `--next` flag will update your current stable version to the next/beta version - `v17.3.0-next.0`.

> *NOTE: The stable version is `v17.2.1` as of writing this. You can disregard this step once the `v17.3` becomes a stable version.*

Since Advanced Markers requires Map ID, you should make sure to use a [Map ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id).

Now instead of using `<map-marker />`, you should use the `<map-advanced-marker />`. Your code should look something like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<google-map 
  height="400px"
  width="750px"
  [center]="center"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  mapId="MAP_ID_HERE"
  >
    @for (position of markerPositions; track position) {
      <map-advanced-marker [position]="position" />
    }
</google-map>
```

**app.component.tsx**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: 24, lng: 12 };
  zoom = 4;
  markerPositions: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[] = [{ lat: 24, lng: 12 }];
}
```

Here's a [proof of concept devbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/lively-cherry-2l9yjv?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdmf0006346i42cwigm0%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0002346iqgzm4o6q%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0004346i5nupe49a%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0005346ib6rqdvga%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt5hwdme0002346iqgzm4o6q%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0002346iqgzm4o6q%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt5hwdme0005346ib6rqdvga%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0005346ib6rqdvga%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt5i00yu002h346ijqljzg33%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4200%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5i00yu002h346ijqljzg33%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt5hwdme0004346i5nupe49a%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0004346i5nupe49a%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt5i04jj0043346ikr6scewr%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5hwdme0003346ilj1xkl0v%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5i04jj0043346ikr6scewr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt5i04w701r9dclxdsm1ebb4%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). (just change the MAP_ID and API_KEY with your own)